# PHP \DateTime vs date() DST shift bug?

Tags: php, date, datetime, dst

Hi I have a problem with PHP's DateTime.

Consider the following script:

```
  date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Paris");
  echo $tz = date_default_timezone_get();
  echo "\n";

  $dt = new \DateTime("2017-10-29 00:00:00");
  $i = (int)$dt->format('U');
  $i_max = $i + 3600*5;
  for(; $i < $i_max ; $i+=3600){
        $dt = new \DateTime();
        $dt->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone($tz));
        $dt->setTimestamp($i);

        echo $i."\n";
        echo $dt->format('c T e')."\n";
        echo date('c T e', $i)."\n";
        echo "\n";
  }
```

It loops between 5 "hour" timestamps thru october french DST.
Then it displays the date in ISO8601 and its timezone identifier and abbreviation.

The result is the following:

```
Europe/Paris

1509228000
2017-10-29T00:00:00+02:00 CEST Europe/Paris
2017-10-29T00:00:00+02:00 CEST Europe/Paris

1509231600
2017-10-29T01:00:00+02:00 CEST Europe/Paris
2017-10-29T01:00:00+02:00 CEST Europe/Paris

1509235200
2017-10-29T02:00:00+01:00 CET Europe/Paris
2017-10-29T02:00:00+02:00 CEST Europe/Paris

1509238800
2017-10-29T02:00:00+01:00 CET Europe/Paris
2017-10-29T02:00:00+01:00 CET Europe/Paris

1509242400
2017-10-29T03:00:00+01:00 CET Europe/Paris
2017-10-29T03:00:00+01:00 CET Europe/Paris
```

Look at the 3rd iteration the result between DateTime->format() and date() differs.

The DateTime shows this:

**2017-10-29T02:00:00+01:00 CET Europe/Paris**

But it should show the same thing as date():

**2017-10-29T02:00:00+02:00 CEST Europe/Paris**

Where is my mistake ??

--EDIT--

Hi, here is another script that point directly the "bug":

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Paris");

$dt = new \DateTime();
$dt->setTimestamp(1509235200);
echo $dt->format('c T e')."\n";

echo date('c T e', 1509235200)."\n";
```

displays:

```
2017-10-29T02:00:00+01:00 CET Europe/Paris
2017-10-29T02:00:00+02:00 CEST Europe/Paris
```

and should display:

```
2017-10-29T02:00:00+02:00 CEST Europe/Paris
2017-10-29T02:00:00+02:00 CEST Europe/Paris
```

Comment: Why don't you use DateInterval, and work with the DateTime object and periods rather than using unix timestamps that are UTC and not DTS-aware

Comment: I'm trying to modelize a way to store datetime+dst data in mysql and I found that bug. The loop is just for the example purpose. What I don't understand is why DateTime et date() behaves differently.

Comment: After this code '$i = $dt->format('U');' is executed, $i is a string, you then use it as a number, so you will get unexpected results.

Comment: Where is $tz set?

Comment: vascowhite: I corrected the start of the script and added a (int) cast for format('U'), that unfortunately changed nothing.

Comment: I didn't think it was the problem, just pointing out a poor programming practice. I suspect you are falling foul of DST changes here as Europe changes on that date at that time.

Comment: I don't understand, actually that is what I need: I would like to store time as timestamp in mysql and convert it to local time and make operations on it.

Comment: Hi, does anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that inconsistence related to PHP bug [74274](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74274). The problem is that DateTime working wrong in that case. It becomes obvious if you will run that code:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Paris");
$timestamp = 1509235200;
$dt = new \DateTime();
$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp);
echo $timestamp."\n";
echo $dt->getTimestamp()."\n";
```

It will prints

```
1509235200
1509238800
```